# Java Streams -- How to filter based on function output correctly

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

Edit:

Basically I want to filter all the entries based on whether entry.getObject() is a string that contains value "value".

---

So I have a block of code that looks something like this:

```
list.stream()
    .filter((entry) -> entry.getObject() != null)
    .filter((entry) -> entry.getObject() instanceof String)
    .filter((entry) -> ((String)entry.getObject()).toLowerCase().contains(value))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The main problem is that I can't figure out how to structure this to persist the value of entry.getObject(), and I can't figure out how to manipulate the output of of entry.getObject() without losing sight of the entry that yielded the value.  Earlier attempts looked more like this:

```
list.stream()
    .map((entry) -> entry.getObject())
    .filter((object) -> entry instanceof String)
    .map((object) -> (String)entry)
    .filter((str) -> str.toLowerCase().contains(value))
    /* ... */
```

But then I couldn't figure out any way to relate it to the entry in the list that I started out with.

Comment: What is class corresponding to entry?

Comment: If I understand your need correctly you want to reflect your change on the String in the corresponding entry?

Comment: No, basically I want to filter based on a property of a string that I get from "entry", but to determine that property, I also need to map and filter the string at various stages.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might look like this:

```
list.stream()
    .filter((entry) -> Arrays.stream(new Entry[] {entry})

        // Map from entry to entry.getObject()
        .map((entry) -> entry.getObject())

        // Remove any objects that aren't strings

        .filter((object) -> entry instanceof String)

        // Map the object to a string
        .map((object) -> (String)entry)

        // Remove any strings that don't contain the value
        .filter((str) -> str.toLowerCase().contains(value))

        // If there is a product remaining, then entry is what I want
        .count() > 0)

    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way, we can split off and analyze entry.getObject() without multiple calls to get the value back at each step.

Comment: Use Arrays.stream() to stream an array without constructing an intermediate list

Comment: @Pausbrak Will do!  Edited in.

Comment: You don’t even need an array, if you want a single element stream. You can just use `Stream.of(entry)`. On the other hand, you don’t even need a Stream here. You can use `Optional.of(entry)`, chain the `map` and `filter` ops just like with a stream and instead of `.count() > 0` use `.isPresent()`.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like

```
list.stream()
    .map( (e) -> new Entry(e, e.getObject()) )
    .filter( (p) -> p.getValue() instanceof String )
    //...
    .map( (p) -> p.getKey() )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using Map.Entry or swing.Pair (or roll your own tuple like structure)